# iPad - Different designs for landscape and portrait mode

Tags: ipad, landscape-portrait

I'm making an application for iPad in Xcode in template Master-detail application. I need to do a design for portrait mode and another for landscape mode. My first idea was make two `UIView`s and make a rule: if portrait, show `View1`, if landscape, show `View2`. But I have text fields in it and when the user will be typing something inside and then rotate the device, text will be deleted, because it will be another `UIView`... Can anybody help me, how to do it, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can have one view and use `springs and struts` or use `autolayout`.
2. You can also add views and hide/show them based on the orientation change.
3. You can change the size and position of the view on orientation change.